# Using Odoo PDF viewer widget or a different Odoo widget for displaying images without uploading an image

Tags: image, pdf, url, odoo, widget

I'm trying to use the pdf viewer widget or image. I know that to display the pdf/image you have to have it downloaded to a directory so that you can pull it from there. But I wonder if there is a way to show image without uploading it. Is there is a way to use an image viewer/pdf widget or anything else that can accept a link that can be programmed into a database?

I added a new field: image_url = fields.Char(string="Image URL") and updated form view: field name="image_url" widget="image" options="{'preview_image':
'https://www.usnews.com/media/best-states/overall-rankings-2021.pdf'}"/>

I also tried adding a link to an online pdf file to the database table in PG Admin but that didn't work and it didn't display the pdf.

Is there anything like this in Odoo, where I can have a functionality of showing an image/pdf through the URL, where I can input external image URLs directly into the image_url field of my model?